# Check if two collections are the same (ignoring order) using a custom equality function

Tags: java, guava, equality

I'm having two collections of Foo. I can not change the implementation of Foo and Foo's equals function is implemented incorrectly. I can also not inherit from Foo. I do custom equality function: I've implemented using guava's Predicate function. To give you an idea, the implementation looks a bit like this.

```java
new Predicate<Pair<Foo, Foo>>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(@Nullable Pair<Foo, Foo> input) {
          Foo one = input.getFirst();
          Foo two = input.getSecond();
          return Objects.equals(one.getId(), two.getId());
        }
      };
```

Now I need to check if my two collections of Foo contain the same items **ignoring the order**

I'm looking for the best way to do this using this custom equality function.

Comment: Can you use Sets instead? Otherwise you could check that list2 `containsAll` items from list1 and vice versa.

Comment: Any implementation of Set that I know uses the equals function for equality. If there was an implementation of set where you can define a custom equality function like the one I had (or similar) then that would be a great solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap your class in a Guava [`Equivalence`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) and store that in the Sets.

```
Equivalence<Foo> eq = new Equivalence<Foo>{
// implement equals and hashcode
};
Set<Equivalence<Foo>> set1 = new HashSet<>();
set1.add(eq.wrap(someFoo));
```

That way you could do a bidirectional `containsAll()` or do

```
Sets.difference(set1, set2).isEmpty()
```

Comment: Ooh this Equivalence class looks very promising :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a custom `Predicate`, why not a simple `SortedSet` with custom `Comparator`?

```
    Comparator<Foo> comparator = new Comparator<Foo>() {

        public int compare(Foo o1, Foo o2) {
            return //your custom comparison
        }
    };
    SortedSet<Foo> sortedSet1 = newTreeSet(comparator);
    sortedSet1.addAll(firstCollection);
    SortedSet<Foo> sortedSet2 = newTreeSet(comparator);
    sortedSet2.addAll(secondCollection);

    sortedSet1.equals(sortedSet); //this is what you want
```

Comment: While this should technically work, it violates the contract of Comparator which suggests that a 0 is returned iff the two objects are equal

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to have sorted list after operation, copy it or use answer with `Set` (but with `Set` [1,1,1] == [1]).

```
public class ListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 4);

        System.out.println(compare(list1, list2, (a, b) -> a - b));
        System.out.println(compare(list1, list3, (a, b) -> a - b));
    }

    private static <E> boolean compare(List<E> list1, List<E> list2, Comparator<E> comparator) {
        if(list1.size() != list2.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        Collections.sort(list1, comparator);
        Collections.sort(list2, comparator);
        Iterator<E> iterator1 = list1.iterator();
        Iterator<E> iterator2 = list2.iterator();
        while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
            if(comparator.compare(iterator1.next(), iterator2.next()) != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```